# Como criar uma lista de Datas com dia especifico

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Estou trabalhando em ASP com MVC 4, e prendo criar uma lista de datas a partir dos dados inseridos pelo utilizador. Por exemplo, o utilizador insere o dia do mês em que irá ser feita uma certa ocorrência. Insere ainda a data de início onde vai começar e a data de fim para gerar as datas.
Por exemplo:

O utilizador insere o Dia `19` data de início a `05/02/2014` e data de fim a `20/05/2014`
Eu no controller tenho de gerar uma lista de datas do tipo:

19/02/2014
19/03/2014
19/04/2014

Comment: No exemplo acima, está faltando a data 19/05/2014?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o *[AddMonths()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths.aspx)*, varias linguagens possuem um método semelhante a esse implementado.

Segue o exemplo usando como base a data atual, e incrementando dois meses a ela:

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;  
    DateTime modifiedDatetime = now.AddMonths(2);
```

No seu caso, a diferença estaria em criar a data inicial baseada na entrada do usuário e armazenar isso numa lista.

[Exemplo de uso](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/aspnet-date-time-example-how-to-add_9889.html)

```
    var DataGerada = new DateTime(DataIni.Year, DataIni.Month, dia);

    int i = DateTime.Compare(DataGerada,DataFim);

    if( i > 0){
            //DataGerada é maior do que DataFim, interrompa processo e retorne a lista
    }else{
            //DataGerada é menor ou igual que DataFim, adicione DataGerada à lista
    }

    //A cada iteração execute novamente DataGerada.AddMonths(1)
```

[DateTime.Compare referência](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.datetime.compare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Sim, mas a questão não é essa. A questão é eu estar a gerar datas entre as datas de início e da data de fim. Como é que faço a validação para criar apenas datas entre essas duas datas.

Comment: Você compara as duas datas para saber se copntinua gerando outras, ou se iterrompe o processo. Adicionei outro trecho de código como exemplo

Comment: Sim, já acabei por achar a solução. Obrigado na mesma pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a abordagem sugerida pelo Guilherme, fiz uma pequena implementação de um método que retorna as datas no intervalo desejado.

```
public List<DateTime> GerarDatas(DateTime inicio, DateTime fim, int dia)
{
    List<DateTime> datas = new List<DateTime>();

    DateTime data = inicio.AddDays(dia - inicio.Day);
    if (inicio.Day > dia)
    {
        data = data.AddMonths(1);
    }

    while (data < fim)
    {
        datas.Add(data);
        data = data.AddMonths(1);
    }

    return datas;
}
```

Como utilizar:

```
List<DateTime> datas = program.GerarDatas(new DateTime(2014, 2, 5), new DateTime(2014, 5, 20), 19);
foreach (DateTime data in datas)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.ToShortDateString());
}
```